# Error in Neovim with java configuration, what can I do?

Tags: neovim

[coc.nvim]: Error on notification "doHover": hover provider not found for current buffer, your language server don't support it.

How can I fix this? I installed Hover for java.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by instalilng java 11

it's a requirement for coc vim

> If you do not have a Java Development Kit correctly set
> Download and install a recent Java Development Kit (latest Java 11 is the minimum requirement).

https://github.com/neoclide/coc-java